# OSError: [Errno 57] Socket is not connected (socket programming in python macos)

Tags: python, sockets

I have a p2p network that peers ask tracker (server) for each other port number (with udp) and make a **TCP** connection to each other (p2p) with tcp on the same port that they have made **UDP** connection with server (tracker). These are done properly.

Client server (udp to tracker) works fine but when one peer wants to connect to another peer with tcp connection fails and I don't know why it happens.

### Client Peer Code:

```py
tcp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcp_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', seeder)) # seeder is server peer port number
tcp_socket.send('a.txt'.encode())
file_content = tcp_socket.recv(1024).decode()
print(file_content)
```

### Server Peer Code:

```py
tcp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcp_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', port))
tcp_socket.listen(3)
while True:
    connection, _ = tcp_socket.accept()
    filename = tcp_socket.recv(1024).decode() #error at this line
    print('request: ', filename)
```

*(a peer has udp and tcp connection on the same port. server peer's tcp handler is running in separate thread from its udp handler)*

#### Error in client peer:

```
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

#### Error in server peer:

```
OSError: [Errno 57] Socket is not connected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are trying to use the recv method on the listening socket instead on the accepted (connected) socket. You should replace the `tcp_socket.recv` with `connection.recv`:

```
tcp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcp_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', port))
tcp_socket.listen(3)
while True:
    connection, _ = tcp_socket.accept()
    filename = connection.recv(1024).decode()
    print('request: ', filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting a `recv` on the listening socket `tcp_socket`, not the accepted socket `connection`. The server errors and exits causing the error on the client. Instead, do

```
tcp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcp_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', port))
tcp_socket.listen(3)
while True:
    connection, _ = tcp_socket.accept()
    filename = connection.recv(1024).decode() #error at this line
    print('request: ', filename)
```

There is another problem. TCP does not guarantee that you recv on the same byte boundaries that you send. You need a way for the server to know that it has a fully received message before it can start to decode. Otherwise you risk a partial-character decode error.

You should also decide on a string encoding method otherwise you risk the default on different machines being different.

One option is to always use UTF-8 and to use a newline to known when a message can be decoded.